# Symfony2 cascade on update

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2.7 with Doctrine and ihave a problem after updating an entity's id, here's the problem :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE Vmrs SET id = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [14, 8]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`stageocp`.`vmr_reservation`, CONSTRAINT `FK_755A06C0552D88B6` FOREIGN KEY (`vmr_id`) REFERENCES `vmrs` (`id`))
```

I have no problem with the delete action it delets the field in the entity and all the fields in the entity with a foreign key and i want to do the same with updating.

When the entity with the foreign key don't have a field that share the same entity that i update, it works.

here's my code:

the entity that containes the foreign key:

```
/**
* VmrReservation
*
* @ORM\Table()
*@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StageOCP\ProjectBundle\Repository\VmrReservationRepository")
*/
class VmrReservation {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StageOCP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Guest", mappedBy="vmrreservation", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $guests;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StageOCP\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="vmrreservations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StageOCP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Reservation", inversedBy="vmrreservations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $reservation;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StageOCP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Vmr", inversedBy="vmrreservations", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $vmr;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isReserved", type="boolean")
 */
private $isReserved;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}
```

the entity that containes the primary key (the one that i update) :

```
/**
* Vmrs
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Vmrs")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StageOCP\ProjectBundle\Repository\VmrsRepository")
*/
class Vmr
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StageOCP\ProjectBundle\Entity\VmrReservation", mappedBy="vmr", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $vmrreservations;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return Vmrs
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}
```

And here's my controller :

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Vmr entity.
 *
 */
public function editAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('StageOCPProjectBundle:Vmr')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Vmr entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('StageOCPProjectBundle:Vmr:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('StageOCPProjectBundle:Vmr')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Vmr entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $metadata = $em->getClassMetaData(get_class($entity));
        $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_vmr'));
    }

    return $this->render('StageOCPProjectBundle:Vmr:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I want to update the foreign key in the entity vmrresevation when i update the primary key (id) in the entity vmr .

I hope i will find a solution here, and thank you

Comment: Just a question: why alter a primary key?

Comment: Doctrine 2 does not support cascade update for keys.  It's not standard sql behavior.  You can try adding On Update Cascade directly to your mysql relations.  But like DonCallisto has implied:  why do such a thing?  It's only asking for trouble.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) for altering the primary key it's not my logic, i am currently at an internship and the person who is in charge of me asked me to do so,